# How to install Meteorite for windows?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

How to install `Meteroite` for windows? I am new to `Meteor`.I try to install `Router` But before installing the `Router` i known it first has to install `Meteorite`.But `Meteorite` installation only for `Linux and ios`.So is there any possibility to install `Meteorite` in `Windows`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Meteorite is not available for windows as at the time of this post.

You can still install the packages in your app though.

1) You would go to atmosphere.meteor.com and find the package you want e.g iron-router

2) Look for the git of the repository, for iron-router its https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git

3) Create a folder called `packages` in your meteor app if it does not already exist.

4) git clone the repository into the packages directory i.e git clone https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router

5) Rename the folder so it becomes the package name `iron-router` stays the same but some packages will be cloned with different folder names, i.e `meteor-analytics` has to be renamed to `analytics`

6) Add your package to meteor with `meteor add iron-router` in the root directory of your project.

Comment: This isn't working for me, I'm trying to add topojson (https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/topojson, https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-topojson) but I'm not sure if it's the right git repo...

Comment: This helped me out. I know that the functionality of mrt has since been added to the Windows version. However, we are using a private repo for some of our packages and the meteor-builtin does not work with those private repos. So, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We have a branch of meteorite that does work well on windows.

https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/tree/windows-updates

It should just require cloning the repo (or downloading the zip file) and running NPM install on it.

Also, http://win.meteor.com maintains an unofficial version of Meteor for windows. I use it and it works pretty well.

If you have issues making this work, let me know. Thanks.

Sean

Comment: I got it to work under windows using this branch. I had some issues with packages using git submodules, but I created a pull request to fix this. I don't know how long it will take to be merged, but my fork can be found here: https://github.com/danielsvane/meteorite

Answer (score 0):

Officially, Meteor and Meteorite is not available for windows yet.  You can try using the unofficial Windows package of meteor at http://win.meteor.com/.  But there is no such equivalent for Meteorite.

If you like using Windows, I would suggest play with Meteor on Windows using a VMware image of Linux.  I do this using Ubuntu.  This is link showing show I set this up.
http://lucidservices.com/2013/08/10/install-meteor-on-ubuntu/